# RustでP2P通信を行うサンプルはどこかにありませんか？

Tags: rust, p2p

タイトルの通りなのですが、RustでP2P通信を行うサンプルはどこかにありませんか？

https://docs.rs/libp2p/0.31.1/libp2p/
こちらがそれにあたりそうなのですが、英語で読み解くのがとても大変で、、、

まずは2つのコンピュータを接続してデータの送受信をやってみたいので、
それだけのコードをご教示いただけると嬉しいです。

また、最終的にはリアルタイム音声通話にチャレンジしたいのですが、Rustは向いていますでしょうか？
WebRTCよりももっとレイテンシを低いものを作ってみたいのです。

Comment: [A basic chat application demonstrating libp2p and the mDNS and floodsub protocols](https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/blob/master/examples/chat.rs)

Answer (score 2):

Rustのプロジェクトではexamplesというディレクトリにサンプルソースを置くことになっているので、まずそこを探すといいです。
libp2pの場合なら

https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/tree/master/examples

ですね。
例えば

https://github.com/libp2p/rust-libp2p/blob/master/examples/ping.rs

が一番簡単な通信例でしょうか。